# Interactive Grid autosave and refresh (after processing)

Tags: oracle-apex

I have Interactive Grid with Static ID *full_grid*. For auto save I have dynamic action based on JavaScript Expression:

```
$('input[type=text]')
```

which saves grid details:

```
apex.region("full_grid").widget().interactiveGrid("getActions").invoke("save");
```

and it calls process - *Interactive Grid - Automatic Row Processing (DML)*, with custom PL/SQL logic. This part is okay, everything working, but I have **problem with data refresh**. If I updating only one cell (row), everything is okay, because it updating only one row (last modified), but sometimes I need to update 1 or 2 additional rows when updated one of row. I mean if I have 10 rows, when I update 5th row, I update 2nd and 3rd rows as well (in database table), and after processing Interactive  Grid is not updated visually for 2nd and 3rd rows. I understand that I have to refresh Interactive  Grid after processing, but I don't have idea how I can do it. It is possible to call JavaScript function from PL/SQL or maybe there is another solution to refresh Interactive Grid after processing without page submit?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`apex.region("full_grid").widget().interactiveGrid("getActions").invoke("selection-refresh");`

for refresh current line, or

`apex.region("full_grid").widget().interactiveGrid("getActions").invoke("refresh");`

for full refresh.